# Kill process that raises Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'?

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I connect to my Arduino board with the following Python code.

```
device=glob.glob("/dev/ttyUSB*")[0]
time.sleep(1)
arduino = serial.Serial(device, 115200, timeout=5)
```

It generally works, but somehow some other process must be accessing the board after reboot giving me the error

> serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

When unplugging and replugging the USB-plug I can execute the Python code normally, without the error occuring. How can I avoid any other process blocking the port? And how do I find out the reason for this error?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use

```
$ fuser /dev/ttyUSB0
```

to list the PIDs of the processes using the file. Alternatively, if your `fuser` command supports it you can use the `-k` option to kill them.

Comment: This doesn't always work, for example, if you used GNU screen to access a `ttyUSBx device`, and then quit using `Ctrl-C`, you will get "Device busy" but it will not show up with the above command.

Comment: How do I fix it then?!?! :D

Comment: You need to kill the attached screen session. Ideally reattaching via screen and closing it nicely, unideally by killing the screen process that owns the ttyUSB.

Answer (score 10):

In my case

```
$ fuser /dev/ttyUSB0
```

was not working (it showed nothing).

What was working, however, was the following:

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This gave me a list of the processes that were using my serial port and I could simply `kill` them using the `PID` (corresponding to the second column in the list).

Comment: `sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0` worked for me as well, thanks!

Comment: `sudo fuser /dev/ttyUSB0` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

`$ ps ax`

You will see what process is using serial port. Kill that process. This solved it for me.